Binwalk firmware analysis
When I run binwalk on a .rom  using -Me it shows md5cheksum and a 411 signature under dec hex and description are blank why is it blank I’ve used binwalk on bios chip and got data  the binary in question is
https://support.yealink.com/en/portal/docDetail?documentCode=9417deea4d770314

Binwalk scans for signatures (specific byte value sequences) so no results means no signatures were found. The binary could just be machine code. I would run an entropy scan and check for strings to be sure.
